# x64dbg show some text in Chinese

Tags: debuggers, x64dbg

While debugging some 32-bit file with x32dbg, some of the text appear in Chinese and I don't why.
This happened after I moved to a new computer but both of them were Windows 10.
In my old computer I didn't have this issue with the same file.
Any idea how to fix it?
I am working on the latest version Oct 2 2020.
[image]

Comment: It looks like these strings are interpreted as 16-bit wide Unicode strings. It might be a setting somewhere.

Comment: It seems that it is related to Windows because I copied the version I am working on to my vmware and it worked without a problem